# select element in join tables cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i try select one id in a cakephp. I have this:

```
    public function start($id = null) {
        $this->Round->id = $id;
}
```

i try to get a proyect _id from a Round. Proyect and round have have a relationship in BD. 
I do this but it not work:

```
        public function start($id = null) {
            $this->Round->id = $id;
            $this->Round->Project->id
           }
```

And this:

```
               public function start($id = null) {
                 $this->Round->id = $id;
                 $this->Round->project_id
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe let's try to do it simple way.
Round and Proyect have a relationship, so if you have relation between their ID's, you probably can do something like that:

```
$proyect_id = $this->Round->field('proyect_id'));
```

Change this proyect_id in

```
field('proyect_id'));
```

to your foreign key's column name in Round table. It should return value of ID column from Proyect table.

Comment: I need do this in the controller of Round and this not work for me: $this->Round->Project->id

Comment: if I do print_r ($this-> Round-> Project-> id) it shows nothing. and it have proyect id.

Comment: Try with setting your debug level on 2 and use debug($this-> Round-> Project-> id);